# QT layout in layout shrinks automatically

Tags: qt, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt5, pyqt6

I am using Qt Designer to create a main window and I have the following result:

[image]

The above opened with PyQt6 using the following code:

```
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PyQt6 import uic
import sys


class UI(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        uic.loadUi("form.ui", self)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = UI()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

However, in the Qt designer the actual form looks sth like this:

[image]

As you can notice the x, y and z text and line edits look weird and dimensionally different from the Qt Designer.

There I have a layout in layout and for some reason the the inner layout shrinks. Is it actually possible to fix the error in Qt Designer without modifying the code?

Thank you for your attention!

Edit 1:

Outer layout Property - Value pairs:

[image]

Inner layout Property - Value pairs:

[image]

Comment: Please provide the `ui` file.

Comment: @musicamante thanks for your reply! If ```ui``` file is too big, should I still provide it?

Comment: @musicamante I have provided property value pairs for outer and inner layouts. I hope that is enough

Comment: then remove any other widget while ensuring that the UI still is a [mre]. The layout is not sufficient, you may have set other widget properties we don't know about (including the top level window).